# How to send key to parent mainWindow from dialog in QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, sendkeys

I need a virtual keyboard for an embedded linux application (not QML). I couldn't find a better way, so now I am trying to create one. I want a dialog full of buttons that sends keys to parent `mainWindow`. It runs without errors, but happens nothing in `lineEdit`.

### keyboard.cpp

```
Keyboard::Keyboard(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Keyboard)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mainWindow = this->parent();
}

void Keyboard::on_btnA_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "Test1";
    QKeyEvent event(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_A, Qt::NoModifier);
    qDebug() << "Test2";
    QApplication::sendEvent(mainWindow, &event);
    qDebug() << "Test3";
}
```

And in mainWindow.cpp to open keyboard dialog:

```
  keyboard->show();
  ui->lineEdit->setFocus();
```

What is the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typing "a" should send both press and release.

Comment: My lineEdit on mainWindow should have lost the focus when the keyboard dialog opened. How may i catch the event on mainWindow?

Comment: What is the return value of sendEvent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

1. Sending the event to `mainWindow` requires `mainWindow` to handle passing the event to the `QLineEdit` object, without seeing the rest of the code I can't say if this is being done or not; the alternative is sending directly to the `QLineEdit` like this:

   ```
   QApplication::sendEvent(lineEdit, &event);
   ```
2. The `QKeyEvent` constructor also requires a fourth parameter - the string to send, in the example case an `"a"`.

   ```
   QKeyEvent event(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_A, Qt::NoModifier);
   ```

   should be

   ```
   QKeyEvent event(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_A, Qt::NoModifier, "a");
   ```

   to send an `"a"`.

3. Depending on the exact implementation you may also need to send a `QEvent::KeyRelease` after the `QEvent::KeyPress`, i.e.

   ```
   QKeyEvent event1(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_A, Qt::NoModifier, "b");
   QKeyEvent event2(QEvent::KeyRelease, Qt::Key_A, Qt::NoModifier);
   QApplication::sendEvent(edit, &event1);
   QApplication::sendEvent(edit, &event2);
   ```
4. As (2) indicates, the key enumeration (i.e. `Qt::Key_A`) does not send an `"a"` as you would expect, the string that is sent is instead determined by the fourth parameter in the `QKeyEvent` constructor, i.e.

   ```
   QKeyEvent event(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_A, Qt::NoModifier, "a");
   QApplication::sendEvent(lineEdit, &event);
   ```

   Is equivalent to

   ```
   QKeyEvent event(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_B, Qt::NoModifier, "a");
   QApplication::sendEvent(lineEdit, &event);
   ```

5. Using `QKeyEvent` in this manner will probably lead so some unpleasantness in handling backspaces and deletes. It is probably more elegant to simply append the desired character to the `QLineEdit` text,

   ```
   lineEdit->setText(lineEdit->text().append("a"));
   ```

   and use `QLineEdit::backspace()` and `QLineEdit::delete()` to handle `backspace` and `delete` keys.

---

## Example

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <qwidget.h>
#include <qmainwindow.h>
#include <qlineedit.h>
#include <qboxlayout.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow* main = new QMainWindow;
    QWidget* central = new QWidget();
    QBoxLayout* layout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::LeftToRight);
    central->setLayout(layout);
    QLineEdit* edit = new QLineEdit(central);
    edit->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    layout->addWidget(edit);

    edit->setText("sometext");
    edit->backspace();
    edit->setText(edit->text().append("a"));

    main->setCentralWidget(central);
    main->resize(600, 400);
    main->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: My Keyboard dialog is another dialog that is different from MainWindow (lineedit container.) i catch qkeyevent in mainwindow now and  send it to lineedits.